# Post on instagram selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I want to upload image or video and post it on instagram with python selenium

I tried this :

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_0TPg").send_keys('/path/to/the/picture')
```

and also this :

```
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(Drive)
element = Drive.find_element_by_class_name("_0TPg")
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys('/path/to/the/picture')
actions.perform()
```

But None Of Them Worked.

Even INSTAPY does not work.

I will be grateful if someone helps me!

[Insagram Mobile Emilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTomO.png)

(Mobile Emilation Chrome Instagram)
we should post with clicking "+" sign and open the image

python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do that with 
First install the package 
`pip install instabot` 
And here is the code:

```py
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=`UserName`, password=`Password` ,use_cookie=False)
self.bot=bot
bot.upload_photo(`PATH`, caption=`YOURCAPTION`)
```

This method doesn't work if you want to upload video